# My iPhone 4S has been destroyed... can I backup from the cloud at a later time?

Tags: icloud, wifi, backup, restore

My iPhone 4s is giving me the option to set up as new phone or restore via iTunes or iCloud. I have pictures on my previous phone that is now destroyed. I am unable to maintain a stable wireless connection.

Is there any way I can set up as a new iPhone now and restore all my data later? Or will I lose all my data from my previous phone if I set up a new iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

The backup for the old phone will be stored in the cloud until you delete.  However, if you restore later, you will have to erase any data that you have added since then on the new phone.

Comment: last question, when my phone says time remaining 5 hours??? does that typically mean I have to wait 5 hours, or does that usually go longer?

Comment: It's a rough estimate, usually indicating the worst case scenario for full restore.

Comment: @matt - please ask that as a real question. It's a great one and has some complexity to the answer. @ me here so I can take a stab at answering it if I don't see the question on the site.